# bad authentication data error on twitter API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

I used to do the following to get user timelines:

https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitterapi&count=2

Now that I'm switching to Twitter API 1.1, I thought all I would have to do is this:

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitterapi&count=2

but I'm getting the bad authentication data error from Twitter. I had no authentication setup previously with twitter, does API version 1.1 require authentication?

I guess I can use the Twitter gem, looks like it makes things pretty simple. But I just want to know whether I can use the above URL like I used to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a read of [this](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview#Authentication_required_on_all_endpoints). Your initial assumption is correct, authentication is now required for all endpoints in v1.1. So to answer your question your request is correct you just need to pass an [OAuth](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth) token or use [application-only authentication](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth).